# Resposive admin classes?

Tags: metabox

Does WordPress have default classes that makes possible to use several *(resposive)* columns in admin area / meta boxes? Take a look at the example below: I need inputs to be in separate columns.

Yes, I could do it myself but I find it poinless to load more `CSS` if WP already has the functionality.

---

**HTML code:**

```
<p>
    <label for="first">This is first input</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="first" id="first" value="" size="30" />

    <label for="second">This is second input</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="second" id="second" value="" size="30" />
</p>
```

---

**How it currently looks like:**

[image]

---

**What Im looking for:**

[image]

Comment: I'm not at a computer so I can't check (and can't think of anything now) but what I would do is find an existing area of the admin that does this and inspect the CSS. I'm sure there should be something.

Comment: @CAI What I meant was that maybe someone has had this situation and have found something useful _(e.g there are plenty of tricks discovered by WP veterans which are not documented at all)_, **not** that "Im not in the mood of searching, you better do it". I did look but everything seems to be one column layout or marked very precisely _(very specific element #ids and .classes)_. I couldn't find any suitable markup.

Comment: Of course. I just had another look through (I've recently done some heavy customisation on the backend so I have been looking through it a lot recently anyway) and there's nothing generic. There is - as you said - plenty of specific rules that you *could* use. You probably shouldn't but it's a possibility. `#dashboard-widgets .postbox-container` for instance, responsively goes from 4 columns to 3 to 2 to 1 column. Other than that your stuck to adding your own CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so, it only have responsiveness to the lateral menu. You will have to create your own HTML and CSS responsive structure.